# Retrieving screen orientation with locked orientation

Tags: android, position, location, android-sensors

At first, I know how to retrieve the screen orientation in Android (yet I tried to get the DisplayMetrics and configuration properties), but my issue is that I want to get the screen orientation with a predefined orientation in the activity's Manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name="net.jugl.eight.StartupActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_startup" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I don't seem to be able to get the screen orientation because it always returns that the screen is currently in portrait mode, but there must be a way to lock the orientation of the screen itself and still being able to get the device's "real" rotation. (like if I hold my device in landscape mode but having the application locked to portrait mode)

I know there are Sensors which can determine the device's rotation (I've only tried Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR yet because it matches my selected API level best) but I'd like to keep away from that since it's not *that* reliable.

So what's the best way to attempt this? I currently have no clue.

Comment: Try my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491260/android-invert-sensor-values1-in-portrait-to-positiv-and-flipped-portrait-nega/22491349#22491349 Let me know if it does work.